# Добавить текст в поле textarea и записать этот же текст в переменную по клику на кнопку

Tags: javascript

```js
var submit = document.getElementById('submit');

submit.addEventListener('click', handler);
function handler() {
 var data = document.getElementById('data').textContent;
 alert(data);
}
```

```html
<textarea name="" id="data" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<br>
<button type="submit" id="submit">Отправить</button>
```

Не получается записать в переменную data введённые данные из textarea, Подскажите что почитать и как реализовать? Необходимо для дальнейшей манипуляции с данными. Например, подсчёта количества символов и вывода результата здесь же в окне.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно заменить `textContent` на `value`.

```js
var submit = document.getElementById('submit');

submit.addEventListener('click', handler);

function handler() {
  var data = document.getElementById('data').value;
  alert(data);
}
```

```html
<textarea name="" id="data" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<br>
<button type="submit" id="submit">Отправить</button>
```

Comment: Несколько не догоняю, почему value? Это считается как свойство у объекта - textarea? http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/textarea.html#textarea

Comment: Да, у элемента `textarea` есть свойство `value`, которое является его контентом.

Answer (score 2):

У `textarea` есть значение `value`, вы можете забирать его и тогда все будет работать.

```js
var submit = document.getElementById('submit');

submit.addEventListener('click', handler);
function handler() {
  var data = document.getElementById('data').value;
  console.log(data);
}
```

```html
<textarea name="" id="data" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<br>
<button type="submit" id="submit">Отправить</button>
```